# What does 'barrel' mean in the phrase "get sb over a barrel"?

Tags: word-usage

In the dictionary:

> **have someone over a barrel**
>   If someone has you over a barrel, they have put you in a situation where you are forced to do what they want.
>
> **barrel**
>   a hollow cylindrical container or unit

I had understood `have someone over a barrel` as a whole phrase, what does barrel mean in the phrase "get somebody over a barrel" ?

Comment: If by *sb* you mean *somebody*, please write out the full word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the large wooden container for beer or similar.

A prisoner would be tied, face forward, onto a board with a barrel in the middle. This would bend their body forward. They could then be whipped or beaten with a paddle as punishment. This is illustrated in this picture from wikipedia

[image]